# How to store 'adb devices -l' output to a text file?

Tags: adb, logging, command-line

Is there any way to store the output of `adb devices -l` command to a text file?

Note: output of `adb devices -l` command is

```
List of devices attached
1101530abd5a234b       device product:j1pop3hjv model:SM_J110H device:j1pop3h
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `>` after *any* command followed by file name or file path where you want to save the file. It  would look like this:

```
adb devices -l > FILE_NAME
```